# Loss when starting fine tuning is higher than loss from transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Since I start fine tuning with the weights learned by transfer learning, I would expect the loss to be the same or less. However it looks like it starts fine tuning using a different set of starting weights.

Code to start transfer learning:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                              include_top=False, 
                                              weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 1000
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), 
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    validation_steps=len(val_generator),
                    callbacks=[callback],)
```

Output from last epoch:

```
Epoch 29/1000
232/232 [==============================] - 492s 2s/step - loss: 0.1298 - accuracy: 0.8940 - val_loss: 0.1220 - val_accuracy: 0.8937
```

Code to start fine tuning:

```
model.trainable = True

# Fine-tune from this layer onwards
fine_tune_at = -20

# Freeze all the layers before the `fine_tune_at` layer
for layer in model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
  layer.trainable =  False

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-5),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history_fine = model.fit(train_generator,
                         steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), 
                         epochs=epochs,
                         validation_data=val_generator,
                         validation_steps=len(val_generator),
                         callbacks=[callback],)
```

But this is what I see for the first few epochs:

```
Epoch 1/1000
232/232 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3459 - accuracy: 0.8409/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py:960: UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images
  "Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be "
232/232 [==============================] - 509s 2s/step - loss: 0.3459 - accuracy: 0.8409 - val_loss: 0.7755 - val_accuracy: 0.7262
Epoch 2/1000
232/232 [==============================] - 502s 2s/step - loss: 0.1889 - accuracy: 0.9066 - val_loss: 0.5628 - val_accuracy: 0.8881
```

Eventually the loss drops and passes the transfer learning loss:

```
Epoch 87/1000
232/232 [==============================] - 521s 2s/step - loss: 0.0232 - accuracy: 0.8312 - val_loss: 0.0481 - val_accuracy: 0.8563
```

Why was the loss in the first epoch of fine tuning higher than the last loss from transfer learning?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Have you found a solution or at least a reasonable explanation on why it is happening ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

According to Tensorflow, Keras page on Transfer learning and fine-tuning [link](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning). The params of the Batch Norm layer should be left alone.

> Importantly, although the base model becomes trainable, it is still running in inference mode since we passed training=False when calling it when we built the model. This means that the batch normalization layers inside won't update their batch statistics. If they did, they would wreck havoc on the representations learned by the model so far.

Below is what I did that fixed the issue of sudden increase in loss after unfreeze layers:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNet

img_width, img_height, num_channel = 128, 128, 3
conv_base = MobileNet(
             include_top=False,
             input_shape=(img_width, img_height, num_channel),
             pooling="avg")
conv_base.trainable = False

check_layer = layers.BatchNormalization() # a dummy layer

for layer in conv_base.layers[-50:]: # unfreeze 50 layers from the top
        # check if the layer is of type BatchNorm
        if type(layer) != type(check_layer): 
            layer.trainable = True

print(conv_base.summary(show_trainable=True)) # checking the layers' trainability
```